# How to install iOS 12 public beta?

Tags: windows, mac

It is possible to open a .xip file in Windows 10?

I downloaded iOS 12 Beta file to manually update my iPhone, but I'm running a Windows OS.

Can I do this? How?

Comment: "It is possible to open a .xip file in Windows 10?" No, DrZoo has the correct method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not quite how you do it. To get iOS 12 public beta on your phone, do the following:

1. Sign up on the [Apple Beta](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/) page and register your Apple ID.
2. Log in to the Beta Software Program
3. Click Enroll on your iOS device.
4. Go to beta.apple.com/profile on your iOS device.
5. Download and install the configuration profile.
6. This will enable the beta version available in the settings app, under General, Software Update.

[Source](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iosapps/install-ios-12-beta-3525099/)